# How to get the DIV value from inside another div

Tags: javascript

How to get the value of a `class="selected"` within the div, I have tried the following code but I get the `undefined`

```
<div class="myTest1" title="testTitle1" id="test1" >       
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div>answer 3</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 4</div>     
</div>
<div class="myTest2" title="testTitle2" id="test2">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 3</div>
        <div>answer</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="myTest3" title="testTitle2" id="test3">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 2</div>
        <div >answer 3</div>
        <div>answer 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

I realized that my code is not optimized and I'm using three `for` loops.

```
    var test1= document.getElementById("test1");
    var test2= document.getElementById("test2");
    var test3= document.getElementById("test3");       
   
    for (var i=0; i<test1.length; i++) {
        var sel1 = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        alert(quizAns1[i].innerHTML);
    }
   
    for (var i=0; i<test2.length; i++) {
        var sel2 = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        alert(sel2[i].innerHTML);
    }
   
    for (var i=0; i<test3.length; i++) {
        var sel3 = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        alert(sel3[i].innerHTML);
    }
```

Comment: It is better not to download all the elements directly  `var sel = document.querySelectorAll(".selected"); for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) { console.log(sel[i].textContent); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query directly for the elements based on the class and then loop over the results. Also, give each question the same class so they can be grouped more easily.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.selected").forEach(function(item, index){
  // Use .closest to get the nearest matching ancestor:
  alert("For question " + item.closest(".myTest").id + ", you answered: " + item.textContent); 
});
```

```html
<div class="myTest" title="testTitle1" id="test1" >       
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div>answer 3</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 4</div>     
</div>
<div class="myTest" title="testTitle2" id="test2">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 3</div>
        <div>answer</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="myTest" title="testTitle2" id="test3">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 2</div>
        <div >answer 3</div>
        <div>answer 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Scott, but if I want to know what is `test1` selected value or `test2` value ?

Answer (score 1):

And your fault is trying to get an element's lenght.

```
console.log(test1.length);//this will return null
```

I am new. I couldn't just leave a comment, so

Answer (score 1):

Just add same 'class' on all DIV, and did changes in code.
and check snippet I hope is what you look for.

```js
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
    for (i = 0, max = elementList.length; i < max; i++) {
      let question = elementList[i].closest(".myTest").getAttribute ("id");
        console.log(`Question: ${question} -> Answer: ${elementList[i].textContent} `);
    }
```

```html
<div class="myTest" title="testTitle1" id="test1" >       
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div>answer 3</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 4</div>     
</div>
<div class="myTest" title="testTitle2" id="test2">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 3</div>
        <div>answer</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="myTest" title="testTitle2" id="test3">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 2</div>
        <div >answer 3</div>
        <div>answer 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to accurately target the div in question each time, which I imagine you would under real conditions:

```
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
var test2 = document.getElementById("test2");
var test3 = document.getElementById("test3"); 

var sel1 = test1.querySelector('.selected');
var sel2 = test2.querySelector('.selected');
var sel3 = test3.querySelector('.selected');
```

Comment: While this works, relying on `id`'s is never a good solution (especially in the real world). It creates brittle code that doesn't scale. It's just as accurate and much more flexible to query based on classes or relative positions in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

**You should do this either**

```
<div class="myTest1" title="testTitle1"  >    
    <div id="test1">
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div>answer 3</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 4</div>   
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="myTest2" title="testTitle2">
    <div  id="test2">
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 3</div>
        <div>answer</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myTest3" title="testTitle2" >
    <div id="test3" >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 2</div>
        <div >answer 3</div>
        <div>answer 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your `js` this:

```
var test1= document.getElementById("test1");
var test2= document.getElementById("test2");
var test3= document.getElementById("test3");       

for (var i=0; i<test1.length; i++) {
    var sel1 = document.querySelector("#test1 .selected");
    alert(sel1.innerHTML);
}

for (var i=0; i<test2.length; i++) {
    var sel2 = document.querySelector("#test2 .selected");
    alert(sel2.innerHTML);
}

for (var i=0; i<test3.length; i++) {
    var sel3 = document.querySelector("#test3 .selected");
    alert(sel3.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
for(let q = 1; q <= 3; ++q)
  console.log("question", q, document.querySelector("#test" + q).querySelector(".selected").textContent);
```

```html
<div class="myTest1" title="testTitle1" id="test1" >       
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div>answer 3</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 4</div>     
</div>
<div class="myTest2" title="testTitle2" id="test2">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div>answer 2</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 3</div>
        <div>answer</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="myTest3" title="testTitle2" id="test3">
    <div  >
        <div>answer 1</div>
        <div class="selected">answer 2</div>
        <div>answer 3</div>
        <div>answer 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.